# Creating a new Excel File in pywin32

Tags: python-3.x, export-to-excel, pywin32

I'm writing a program that, summarized, takes a notepad file and saves it as a excel file.

Right now my program opens up a blank excel file I have created, just "Book1.xls":

```
xlApp = Dispatch("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Visible=0
xlWb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(file_path+"/Book1.xls")
workBook = xlApp.ActiveWorkbook
sheet = xlApp.ActiveSheet
```

and it uses `Book1.xls` to write into and format as is required, then saves it as another file name using

```
workBook.SaveAs(new_file_path+'/UpdatedSheet.xls')
```

I want to know how to simply create a new excel file to write to, then save as a file.  Without the need of having `Book1.xls` already created in a specific directory.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create a new workbook using the Add method of the Workbooks object:

```
>>> import win32com.client as win32
>>> excel = win32.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
>>> workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add()
>>> workbook.SaveAs(new_file_path+'/UpdatedSheet.xls')
```